# Getting an empty array, when storing categories of a post

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, body-parser

I have two schemas one being the category schema, and the other being the article schema. A user has to enter title, summary and add some categories. The categories are getting uploaded to the category schema but is not getting linked with articles. It showing empty array.

```
app.post("/upload", async (req,res) => {
const { title, summary, categoryIds } = req.body;

const categoryNamesArray = req.body.categories.split(',').map(category => category.trim());

try {
  // Find or create categories based on user input
  const categoryObjects = [];
  for (const categoryName of categoryNamesArray) {
    let category = await Category.findOne({ name: req.body.categories });

      if (!category) {
        category = new Category({ name: req.body.categories });
        await category.save();
      }
      categoryObjects.push(category);
  }

  const newArticle = new article({
    title: title,
    summary: summary,
    category: categoryObjects 
  });

  // await newArticle.populate('categories');
  await newArticle.save();

  console.log('Article saved successfully:', newArticle);
  res.status(200).send('Article saved successfully');
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
  res.status(500).send('Error saving article');
}
```

I tried to remove the category schema and, add categories inside the article schema, but it also returned an empty array

Comment: Replace your `req.body.categories ` by `categoryName` in your `for` loop

Comment: You may want to include the schemas and the details of the data in the request body in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your filter is wrong.

```
let category = await Category.findOne({ name: req.body.categories });
```

should be

```
let category = await Category.findOne({ name: categoryName });
```

And similarly correct it here as well

```
category = new Category({ name: req.body.categories });
category = new Category({ name: categoryName });
```

Comment: Thankyou, I tried this but it is still returning an empty array.

Comment: please edit your question with latest code.